# Copying CSV Value changes the format

Tags: vba

I try to loop over a folder which contains (n) .CSV Files (These files are already imported and separated (Splitted)).

i Copy  specific Columns (S:V) from the sources files to my Workbook (Makrofile.xlsm).

The Problem :

The Format of Numbers in Sourcefiles is : for Example 5,8987 after Copying these Numbers and Pasting them, the format changes to 558.97

in the best Case after changing  the Format before copying from the Sourcefile i change the format to

Columns("S:S").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.000"

Then Copy and Close The Sourcefile then i paste to my (Makrofile.xlsm) The result is : 5.5897

I have a German Excel and the comma ist (,).I cant do Operations with this Number .

Any Idea to keep the format of Values from the CSV as it is after pasting ?

Thank You all very Much

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Range.PasteSpecial Method? I haven't worked much with CSV files, so I might be a bit off here, but since I haven't seen your code, you might not have tried it yet.

```
expression.PasteSpecial(Paste, Operation, SkipBlanks, Transpose)
'Implementation:

Workbooks("YourWorkbook").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Or here's some code from MSDN

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("C1:C5").Copy
    .Range("D1:D5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
End With
```

You have choices between a few things like: xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, xlPasteFormats, xlPasteValues, xlPasteAll. You might want to experiment with what works best for you.

If this isnt' what you're looking for just let me know and I'll remove it.